# Display dynamic Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have bound data to Telerik MVC Grid. Following is the code given in cshtml :

```
@( Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.UserInfo)
.Name("User")
.Columns
(
    columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(col => col).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(col => col.Email);
        columns.Bound(col => col.EYLoginID).Title("Windows User Name");
        columns.Bound(col => col.Title);
        columns.Bound(col => col.Phone);
        columns.Bound(Model.CompanyDefinitionName).Title("Location");
        columns.Bound(col => col.IsExternalContact).Title("External");
    }
 )
 .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server())
 .Sortable()
```

)

Here `Model.CompanyDefinitionName` is a string which I need to display along with other columns. But I am getting an error since `Model.CompanyDefinitionName` is not part of the entity. How will I display this as column ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a template column:

```
columns.Template(@<text>
   @Model.CompanyDefinitionName
</text>).Title("Location");
```